# jQuery add class numericly up to x and start over

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, numbers, css-selectors

With jQuery I can add consecutive numeric classes to list items like so:

```
  $(".item-list li").each(function (i) {
      $(this).addClass("item-list-" + i);
   });
```

So with an HTML structure as such:

```
<ul class="item-list">
  <li>an item</li>
  <li>another item</li>
  <li>another item</li>
  <li>another item</li>
  <li>another item</li>
</ul>
```

... this will output nice list item classes in numeric order:

```
class="item-list-0"
class="item-list-1"
```

... etc...

What I'm trying to do is number of to *4 items and then start the numbering over* at zero again. I figured I'd have to use `nth` child within my numeric `+ i` code but I just have not been able to find any documentation on this. Everything that I've found relates to finding an nth element but not starting a count over after a specified amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this using modulus operator itself:

```
$(".item-list li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass("item-list-" + (i%4));
});
```

#### Output markup

```
<ul class="item-list">
    <li class="item-list-0">an item</li>
    <li class="item-list-1">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-2">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-3">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-0">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-1">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-2">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-3">another item</li>
    <li class="item-list-0">another item</li>
</ul>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TVfBw/)

Comment: haha, love the color coding. Perfect, thanks, now I know what it's called, i.e. `modulus operator`.